# Returning maximum values from a string in specific set of columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, max

I have output from a program similar to this dataframe:

```
    df <- data.frame(Pos = c(1, 2, 3), Alel1 = c('A:1', 'T:0', 'C:0.5'),
                 Alel2 = c('T:0', 'C:1', 'A:0.3'), Alel3 = c(NA, NA, 'T:0.2'),
                 Alel4 = c('A:1', 'T:1', 'C:0.5'), Alel5 = c('T:0', 'C:0', 'A:0.5'),
                 Alel6 = c(NA, NA, NA))
```

For each row, I would like to get the major allele of Alel1, Alel 2 and Alel3 (**group1**), and major allele of Alel4, Alel 5, and Alel6 (**group2**). Plus, extra information on how differ the major allel in group 1 and 2(**changing**). 
So, then I get new column/dataframe summarizing the allele information more less like this:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(Group1 = c("A", "C", "C"), 
                  Group2 = c("A","T","0.5C 0.5A"), 
                  Changing = c(0,1,0.5))
```

I am trying to separate alleles from each column and add to a new column using this

```
df$a <- substring(df$Alel1, 3)
df$b <- substring(df$Alel2, 3)
df$c <- substring(df$Alel3, 3)
```

then find the maximum value for each group using this

```
i <- as.character(c("a","b","c"))
j <- max.col(df[i],"first")
```

But, values in **j** return with *NA* instead of the column name, and I don't know how to call the respective allele from that column name. 
Any easier suggestions that give what I intended are very much appreciated!

Comment: How does `df` become `df1`? I don't know what an allele is so I'm struggling to see where eg `Group1 = c("A", "C", "C")` comes from, likewise for the other columns. Is `df1` the desired output?

Comment: yes,, df1 is the desired output that i want. df is the dataset that I have already as an output from another tool. Group1 = c("A", "C", "C") is the maximum alel for each row in alel 1,2,3. So, by simply lookign at df, for row 1, the maximum alel is "A" because of 1, while alel 2 is null, and alel 3 is NA.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```r
i <- as.character(c("a","b","c"))

j <- i[max.col(replace(df[i], is.na(df[i]), -Inf), "first")]
#[1] "a" "b" "a
```

Comment: My intended output is like df1, do you know how to refer back this maximum column to the alel name?